# How does Polipo/tor become globally used?

Tags: proxy, tor, polipo

I installed and configured polipo/tor a while back and one of the things that regularly surprises me is this:

Boot up and Firefox, which is configured to use the polipo SOCKS proxy, always goes through tor (via https://check.torproject.org) but Chromium does not go through tor, till I've been booted for a while.  I suspected it was some global setting that my browsers knew about, so I tried with curl:

```
 $ curl https://check.torproject.org
 ...
 Congratulations. This browser is configured to use Tor.
 ...
```

How is this happening?  Is there something tor does to grab all outbound port 80/443?

Here's my /etc/tor/torrc

```
SocksPort 9050
SocksPolicy accept 127.0.0.1
SocksPolicy reject *
ControlPort 9051
ORPort 9300
RelayBandwidthRate 300 KB
RelayBandwidthBurst 600 KB
DirPort 9301
MyFamily xxx
DisableDebuggerAttachment 0
ExitPolicy reject *:*
```

Here's my /etc/torsocks.conf

```
local = 127.0.0.0/255.128.0.0
local = 127.128.0.0/255.192.0.0
local = 169.254.0.0/255.255.0.0
local = 172.16.0.0/255.240.0.0
local = 192.168.0.0/255.255.0.0
server = 127.0.0.1
server_port = 9050
```

Here's my /etc/polipo/config

```
socksParentProxy = "localhost:9050"
socksProxyType = socks5
```